# ADf mobile application is not deploy in device

Tags: oracle-adf

I use following video for configuring ios setting.

http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/jdeveloper/11gdemos/adfmobiledeployios.html

But, When i deploy application in device i get following error.

```
[03:27:06 PM] xcrun: Error: could not stat active Xcode path '/Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer'. (No such file or directory)
[03:27:06 PM] Command-line execution failed (Return code: 0)
[03:27:06 PM] Deployment cancelled.
[03:27:06 PM] ---- Deployment incomplete ----.
[03:27:06 PM] Failed to package the XCode application.
[03:27:06 PM] Failed to build the iOS application bundle.
[03:27:06 PM] Deployment failed due to one or more errors returned by '/usr/bin/xcrun'. The following is a summary of the returned error(s):
xcrun: Error: could not stat active Xcode path '/Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer'. (No such file or directory)
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears /Volumes/Xcode doesnt exist on your filesystem when you were trying to deploy. Even more so, having Xcode under hte "volumes" directory indicates you have the xcode.dmg file mounted onto your filesystem as a mount and not actually installed on your filesystem.

I made a similar mistake, as the /Volumes/Xcode directory disappeared on me over night one time. To install onto your system, drag the xcode.dmg file onto the applications folder. You can use xcode from there.

After you install Xcode into your applications directory, double check your JDeveloper iOS settings "Tools > Preferences > ADF Mobile > Platforms". Make sure the SDK and xCode directories are correct.

Thanks,

Gavin
http://pitss.com/us